# PHP Array - getting elements from position 1 to 2

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, something like this:

```
array(3) { 
 [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "9" ["userFrom"]=> string(1) "1"  } 
 [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["userFrom"]=> string(1) "1" }
 [2]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["userFrom"]=> string(1) "1" }
}
```

Obviously it will be much longer though.

How can I get all the elements in the array from position 0 to 10 and put them into a new array?

Comment: Try [array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice)

Comment: Are you supposed to iterate the array in chunks of 10?

Answer (score 4):

```
var_dump(array_chunk($input_array, 10));
```

For more info see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Or even

```
var_dump(array_slice($input_array, 0, 10));
```

For more info see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: This won't work if I want positions 11 to 20 for example

Comment: Lol, you ask for 0 to 10, if you want 11 to 20, change the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
$array = array(…);

$newArray = array_slice($array, 0, 10);
```

Provided that `$array` is the upper-most array.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's how you can use a generator to iterate through an array in chunks:

```
function chunker(array $input, $size)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($input); $i += $size) {
        yield array_slice($input, $i, $size);
    }
}

foreach (chunker($data, 10) as $chunk) {
    print_r($chunk);
}
```